# Have C Start Python Interpreter under a USC-2

Tags: python, c, python-embedding

I am trying to run Python embedded within a simple C program. However, when I import a module, I got an error `undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8`.

Upon further investigation, I discovered that the Python interpreter started under `Py_Initialize();` uses UCS-4 encoding whereas the module I am trying to import uses UCS-2 encoding. I am asking if there is a way to initialize the Python Interpreter with the correct encoding. I am using centos7 linux system which mostly uses USC2 and I don't know why the embedded interpreter is using USC-4

C code: embed.c

```
#include <Python.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  Py_Initialize();
  pName = PyString_FromString(argv[1]); //get name of module to import
  pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
}
```

Python

```py
print( __file__ + ": Encoding: " + str(sys.maxunicode)) #How I printed out the interpreter encoding which is 1114111
import torch
```

Makefile

```
gcc -I /usr/include/python2.7 embed.c -o embed -lpython2.7
```

The code compiles but I get this error message: `undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8`.

Comment: are you certain it is using UCS2 - does the file, when run with /usr/bin/python result in a different value being printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to initialize the interpreter with the correct encoding. Whether the interpreter uses UCS2 or UCS4 is a compile-time choice. What you need to do is to recompile the entire module from source. If you do not have the sources for the module, then you must compile the **Python 2.7** from source and be careful to not replace the system python 2.7 with it.

The UCS2 builds were considered a mistake because there the non-BMP characters will be represented as UTF-16 surrogate pairs that now become visible as separate codepoints. That is why Python 3 does not have this compile-time option, as it always uses UCS4 internally for strings that cannot be represented in UCS2.